# Coping text from textarea to div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to copy text from textarea to div using this code but there are line breaks missing.

```
$("#some-div").text($("#some-textarea").val().replace('/\n/g', '<br />'));
```

What's going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870256/how-do-you-preserve-the-line-breaks-in-a-textarea-in-jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text` function will set text, not HTML.

You need replace the newlines in the generated HTML:

```
$("#some-div").text($("#some-textarea").val())
              .html(function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') });
```

Note that you cannot set the HTML directly from the textarea, because that won't escape HTML tags.

Also, unlike PHP, Javascript uses regex literals, so you cannot put a regex in a string.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer but unfortunately it doesn't work in IE ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870256/how-do-you-preserve-the-line-breaks-in-a-textarea-in-jquery)). Here is working code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LWjP6/19/)

Comment: @rotman: Wrong.  That code does not work.  Try typing `<i>`.  This is what I meant in my 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than treating HTML as a string, I would suggest creating DOM nodes. Normalize the textarea value (IE uses `\r\n` rather than `\n`), split the textarea value on line breaks and create text nodes separated by `<br>` elements:

```
var div = $("#some-div")[0];
var lines = $("#some-textarea").val().replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (i) div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i]));
}
```