# jQuery to pull <td> content conditionally

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, extract

Given this table:

```
<table id="issuetbl">
    <tr> <td>aaaa</td> <td><div>whatever</div></td> <td>cccc</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>1111</td><td class="ms-vb"><p>What about rest of line.&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;this needs to show uptoo</p></td> <td>2222</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>3333</td> <td><div>else</div></td> <td>4444</td> </tr> 
</table>
```

This jQuery script pull two tds following  a match (here 1111).. well at least it did until we put some line feeds int the content. It now only pulls up to the nbsp. Only returns:
What about rest of line.

```
var bodyprefixes = [];
$('#issuetbl td:contains(1111)').nextAll().each(function(i, k) {
    var td = $(k), div = td.children();
    bodyprefixes.push(div.length ? div.html() : td.html());
});
alert(bodyprefixes[0]);
alert(bodyprefixes[1]);
```

It's a nice solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/262056/stephen

It's being worked here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8RvgA/3/

Anybody know how we can get the full td for 1111?

Comment: What are you trying to get it to do? Alert every cell in the row, or alert every cell in the row that is not the 1111 cell?  I am kind of lost as to the goal here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('#issuetbl td:contains(1111)').parent()
```

...dunno if this is what you want, I'm just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: I do need the the tags.. especially the <p> tags for new line feeds. Any suggestsions. thanks. – cyberpine 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need entities:

```
bodyprefixes.push(td.text());
```

If you do, yo have to iterate through all children of td

Comment: I do need the the tags.. especially the <p> tags for new line feeds. Any suggestsions. thanks. – cyberpine 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you want.  But if you just want all the data in the same row that has a td with the value '1111', then this should do: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/8RvgA/4/

```
$('#issuetbl td:contains(1111)').nextAll().each(function(i, k) {
    bodyprefixes.push($(k).text());
});
```

Using `.text()` will strip out the tags and ignore all the white spaces

**updated with tags:** http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/8RvgA/5/

```
$('#issuetbl td:contains(1111)').nextAll().each(function(i, k) {
    bodyprefixes.push($(k).html());
});
```

Comment: I do need the the tags.. especially the <p> tags for new line feeds. Any suggestsions. thanks.

Comment: If you need the tags, then your solution should be fine.  Check out the updated post.

Comment: that worked.. sorry but how do I get html formatted text so that it observes line feeds into a multiline textbox.. I tried $('input[title$=Subject]').val(html(bodyprefixes[1])); and .html both show the tags without the formating. Thank!

Comment: Try using $('input[title$=Subject]')[0].value = bodyprefixes[1]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870256/how-do-you-preserve-the-line-breaks-in-a-textarea-in-jquery