# When exactly do strings in HTML require escaping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tags

In almost every tag in HTML, characters like `<`(start tag) and `&`(character escape) must be escaped.

However, inside of a `<script>` tag this does not seem to apply! I am able to define in HTML the characters plainly and also retrieve them using jQuery, for example `var my_unescaped_text = $('script[type="text/mytexttype"]');`

Are there any other tags that do this? Is there some way that I could possibly have this sort of thing become visible in a `<pre>` tag without using javascript? (yeah, I know, that definitely sounds like a tall order...)

What about `<input>` or `<textarea>` tags? One can definitely write these characters in a text input field, and that **is** visible and style-able (which satisfies my perhaps unclear goal). Is there anything else? The text I'm trying to display (pre-javascript processing) is Markdown and a `<pre>` is perhaps best suited for it though a `<textarea readonly="readOnly">` could probably be made to look exactly like a `<pre>`.

Comment: `<script>` tags are a special case, keep your scripts external to HTML and you shouldn't have too many problems otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always escape when embedding arbitrary text into HTML.

However, [special rules](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) apply for the content of the `<script>` tag, and they allow an unescaped `<` *under certain conditions*, namely, that it is not part of a `</script>`. Therefore, the correct encoding of `"<"` in JavaScript is `"\u003c"`.

For [security reasons](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html), you shouldn't use inline JavaScript in the first place. Instead, use [`data-` attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: Would it make more sense to say "However" rather than "Therefore"? Since this seems to indicate that it is perfectly legal to write "<" (as a part of a javascript string for instance) inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: No; it is only legal to write `<` in a JavaScript string in an HTML element if you can *guarantee* it's not followed by `/script` (and similarly, you may need to avoid `-->`. In any case, inline JavaScript is deprecated; see the last paragraph of the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I will do it right and use a `<pre>` and fill it with escaped text then.

Comment: If you want to show the text to the user, yes, that's the best option. You don't need the `<pre>` though - virtually every (semantically applicable) element will do.

Comment: Yup the only thing is now I have to un-escape the text prior to sending it to Markdown processing.

Comment: @StevenLu No, you don't. If you're doing Markdown processing in HTML, you can just [extract the text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of the HTML element. If you're submitting it to a server (with a `<textarea>` in a regular HTML form), HTML encoding will be completely irrelevant. No offense, but I suspect you're making things more complicated than they need to be. You may want to ask a new question about your overall problem.

Comment: Okay, `text()` is supposed to do this. Unfortunately, on IE, `text()` drops all newlines.

Comment: I also happen to do some extended messing around where I convert the bits of markdown which are links into links. Which means in the end I must have a partially escaped string to assign using `html()`. You know what, just take a look at the page. http://stevenlu.net/resume.html

Comment: Can you provide a source to the claim that `text` is broken in IE? It works fine on my system. Your site works fine on IE9/Windows 7 x64.

Comment: perhaps it works fine on ie9 and it definitely should work right on ie10. But it is broken on ie8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502673/jquery-text-function-loses-line-breaks-in-ie   The site works even in ie8 but what I want to get working is to get the original Markdown to display on a javascript-disabled browser, which means moving the markdown out of the `<script>` and into some displayed tag.

Comment: Well, that's an IE8 bug, and the answer contains a workaround, doesn't it? A few more notes about your page: You should really specify an encoding. For a stand-alone site, you may want to optimize the number of requests, so it's fine to use inline JavaScript and CSS. In a general (on applications / larger websites), moving CSS and scripts to external resources allows them to be cached, and allows better security mechanisms. Also note that your site is **broken for users without JavaScript**, and unnecessarily so, since there it's basically just static content.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think i'm not too far away from a solution where I can continue to edit the content easily (Now using HTML-escaped-Markdown I guess) and having some form of it getting displayed in JS disabled browsers (the full layout version would be a slight extra bit of work, or server-side markdown conversion).

Comment: to be absolutely clear, by specifying an encoding you mean `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, yes?

Comment: That, or the newer [`<meta charset="utf-8" />`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-meta-element.html#attr-meta-charset)

Answer (score 0):

The escaping rules depend on HTML version: XHTML has its own rules. Decide which version of HTML you will use, and learn its rules from good tutorials and references.

Regarding the detailed questions:

1. The other element similar to `script` in this issue is `style`. There is also the nonstandard but well-supported `xmp` element, which can be used to present HTML markup as content as-is.
2. No, you cannot change the rules so that the exceptions (when they apply) would apply to `pre` for example.
3. The `input` and `textarea` elements are not special in this respect. You may have been misled by a test like `<input value="a<b">`, which is valid (except in XHTML), because `<` need not be escaped in attribute values. Or by a test like `<input value="&">`, which is allowed (except in XHTML), because `&` is not followed by a name character.

To display markup (including Markdown), the recommended way is to escape each occurrence of `<` and `&` in content, as usual. You can slap `code` markup around, and/or `pre` markup, for other reasons, like formatting or logic, but they do not affect HTML parsing or needs to escape. As mentioned, there’s also `xmp`, which is like `pre` but so that no markup inside the element is recognized, treating all content as-is text, except the end tag `</xmp>`; but colleagues, bosses, or teachers might flame you for using it.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Either you escape `<` and `&` to have them displayed as-is, or you want them to be part of markup as interpreted by a browser. And when your document’s HTML source has `&lt;` in content, the DOM will contain it as `<`, so you need not and should not unescape anything when sending the data for processing. (Provided that you are not using `innerHTML`.)