# Stripping HTML, preserving line breaks for mailto tag

Tags: javascript, mailto

I almost got the answer from the most voted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813167/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-convert-html-to-plain-text-while-preserving-l), but I'm trying to put a div content in a mailto tag body.

```
function getInnerText(el) {
    var sel, range, innerText = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.selectAllChildren(el);
        innerText = "" + sel;
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        innerText = range.text;
    }
    return innerText;
}


function doMailTo() {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var el = document.getElementById("container");
    //alert(getInnerText(el));  //--> works fine

    location.href = "mailto:?subject="+title+"&body="+(getInnerText(el));
}

<a href="javascript:doMailTo();">Email</a>
```

This works great in the alert but the line breaks get lost in the email. Is there a way we can replace the line breaks with %0A%0a ? Or do the same thing in another way?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using `encodeURIComponent()` before passing to the GET param?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, but this `%0D%0A%0D%0A` works for me.