# how to get properly formatted text value from a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the formatted text from a contenteditable='true' div to send to my server.

I used to use a textarea and when you get the value of a textarea it preserves white space and line breaks, but when using a contenteditable div even when using styles such as the following I can not get the properly formatted text:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

For example if I type this into my div:

```
"a
 aa

asdf"
```

I will get this out with textContent:

```
"a aaasdf"
```

Is there any way to get formatted text out of a contenteditable div like a textarea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.innerHTML` to get the linebreaks too.

Readup: [`.innerHTML` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var text = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text;
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='true' id="input">Enter something funny<br>;)</div>

<button id="copy">Copy Text</button>

<div id="output">Text will be copied here.</div>
```

Comment: .innerHTML returns all inner html with < br > and so no ... Instead need use .innerText

Comment: Yes this works great in chrome but innerText doesn't work in firefox. Do you know a cross browser solution?

Comment: @Derek Use `.innerHTML` itself. Works in Firefox, Chrome and IE too. Answer updated.

Comment: @Alexander I dont think `innerHTML` fetching `<br>` will be a problem. OP wants the `formatted` text.

Comment: @Derek cross browser solution var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;

Comment: @Alexander this doesn't work because textContent does not get the formatted text, it just concatenates the contents of the child elements

Comment: I found a cross browser alternative to innerText : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813167/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-convert-html-to-plain-text-while-preserving-l]

Answer (score 2):

Example from: [Extracting text from a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div)

```
function getContentEditableText(id) {
    var ce = $("<pre />").html($("#" + id).html());
    if ($.browser.webkit)
      ce.find("div").replaceWith(function() { return "\n" + this.innerHTML; });
    if ($.browser.msie)
      ce.find("p").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML + "<br>"; });
    if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie)
      ce.find("br").replaceWith("\n");

    return ce.text();
}
```

Or:

```
$.fn.getPreText = function () {
    var ce = $("<pre />").html(this.html());
    if ($.browser.webkit)
      ce.find("div").replaceWith(function() { return "\n" + this.innerHTML; });
    if ($.browser.msie)
      ce.find("p").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML + "<br>"; });
    if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie)
      ce.find("br").replaceWith("\n");

    return ce.text();
};
```

This require jQuery, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter content into a `contenteditable` element, this auto-generates HTML nodes within the target element.<s>so you need to access its `.innerHTML` property and treat the content as HTML, not plain text</s>

You can access this HTML content using the `.innerHTML` property, or you can use `.innerText`, which returns plain text but preserves the formatting as shown in @Rahul Desai's answer and in [this blog post](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/):

```js
document.getElementById('getText').onclick = function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML);
};
```

```html
<div id='edit' contenteditable='true'>Type here</div>
<input id='getText' type='button' value='Get Text' />
```

If I enter

> > Hello
> >         how
> >         are you

into that div and then click the button, the console shows:

```
<p>Hello</p><p>how</p><p><br></p><p>are you</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('getText').onclick = function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML);
};
```

```html
<div id='edit' contenteditable='true'>Type here</div>
<input id='getText' type='button' value='Get Text' />
```